# Silverstripe fluent set locale

Tags: php, cron, silverstripe, fluent

Good afternoon,

Does somebody know if there is a method to set locale manual? I want to update some locale based items in the database by a cronjob, but to make it work I have to set locale based on some variables instead of the locale of the server.

Comment: What SilverStripe/Fluent version are you on?

Comment: Silverstripe 3.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the SilverStripe 3 version of Fluent you can use `Fluent::with_locale` to perform a callback under the context of a given locale, e.g.:

```
Fluent::with_locale('de_DE', function () {
    $myObject = MyObject::create();
    $myObject->Title = 'German title';
    $myObject->write();
});
```

For reference, in the SilverStripe 4 version you can do this instead:

```
FluentState::singleton()->withState(function (FluentState $newState) {
    $newState->setLocale('de_DE');
    // ...
});
```